# RegEx, With Optional Part IN Variable

Tags: python, regex

I am doing this in python, I have a couple variables like this.

```
team = "St. John's"
db_team = "St. John's"  
db_team = "St John's" 
#I am not sure which variable db_team will equal

re.search(team, db_team)
```

but obviously this doesn't work because of the period inside of the team variable, but at the same time i can't just take out all periods from the team variable.  Not sure how to take team variable and match either db_team variable?

Comment: What's your overall objective? You're using regex which allows optional character string matching

Comment: anti earth, sorry i don't understand your question

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape your dots and all other shady stuff.

```
re.search(re.escape(team), db_team)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
team = "St\\.? John's"
```

The `\\` is to escape the `.` and the `?` is to make it optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
team = "St. John's"
db_team1 = "St. John's"
db_team2 = "St John's"

# find an exact match for 'St' without a dot, replace it with 'St.' 

db_team1 = re.sub(r'\bc\b', 'St.', db_team1)
db_team2 = re.sub(r'\bSt(?!\.)\b', 'St.', db_team2)
team = re.sub(r'\bSt(?!\.)\b', 'St.', team)

# then compare strings without regex

if team == db_team1: print "match1"
if team == db_team2: print "match2"
```

The same method of using a standard representation can be extended to include other abbreviations. In this sense, you can consider converting all strings from the db and the user to lower case first.